# MVC4 Dynamic Controller Path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a SiteController class in my MVC4 project,the 'Site' url is working fine, but I need a dynamic url part right after 'Site', I need the url to look like this:

mysite.com/Site/{DYNAMICSTRING}/Users(or whatever)

{DYNAMICSTRING} can be the name of a subsite, so the controller should check if that subsite does actually exist in the database.

Right now I'm using Query strings, but that is not what my client wants.

How can I do that?

**Additional details**

My routing:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
                "Subdomain",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{dynamicString}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Site", action = "Subdomain" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

My controller:

```
    public ActionResult Subdomain(string dynamicString)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

the value of dynamicString is null when I navigate to: /Site/Subdomain/SomeString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure routing. For example if you have Homecontroller:

```
    public class HomeController:Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Subdomain(string dynamicString)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

then you have to configure your routing something like that

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Subdomain",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{dynamicString}/anyOtherParams",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Subdomain", dynamicString = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: I think he doesnt want the action part in it.

Comment: Nice, but how can I retrieve the 'dynamicString' in my controller?

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but in 
public ActionResult Subdomain(string dynamicString)
the dynamic string is null
And @JordyvanEijk is right, I don't really need the {action} part

Comment: Then hardoce your controller and action  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "Home/Index/dynamicString",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", dynamicString = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Thanks , but it still doesn't explain how to retrieve the value of dynamicString in code

Comment: If your action parameter is the same as in routing you have to be able to retrieve value in your action. Could you plese show your routing, controller and url?

Comment: Why you didn't add dynamicString param to routing?

Comment: Do you have any other routing rules? Is it possible that other rule handle your url? You have to put more specific routing rules at the top of routing table;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25140/discussion-between-radislav-and-m-jones)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default", // Route name
            url:"Site/{dynamicstring}", // URL with parameters
            defaults: new {controller = "Site", action = "Index" }   // Defaults
        );
```

you can keep adding parts to the url part like so

```
 url:"Site/{dynamicstring}/{anythingelse}" //  url:"Site/{dynamicstring}/{anythingelse}/{bla}/Test/{hello}/etc..."
```

or you can also have a catch all route like this:"

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default", // Route name
            url:"{*all}", // catch all
            defaults: new {controller = "Site", action = "Index" }   // Defaults
        );
```

and fetch all other parts in your controllers index action, by splitting them on /

Make sure you put the custom route before your default otherwise the default route will pick it up.

in your controller you get something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string dynamicstring, string anythingelse)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

and if you then pass in a url like this:

> http://www.mysite.com/Site/test.nl/jordy

your dynamicstring will have the value "test.nl" and your anythingelse will have "jordy"
I hope this helps